# Média ponderada com exame final

Tags: javascript, if, lógica

Eu preciso **ler 4 notas** **com pesos de 2, 3, 4 e 1**, respectivamente, para cada uma destas notas e devo mostrar esta média acompanhada pela mensagem "Media: ". **Se esta média for maior ou igual a 7.0, imprima a mensagem "Aluno aprovado.". Se a média calculada for inferior a 5.0, imprima a mensagem "Aluno reprovado.". Se a média calculada for um valor entre 5.0 e 6.9, inclusive estas, o programa deve imprimir a mensagem "Aluno em exame.".**

No caso do aluno estar em exame, leia um valor correspondente à nota do exame obtida pelo aluno. Imprima então a mensagem "Nota do exame: " acompanhada pela nota digitada. **Recalcule a média (some a pontuação do exame com a média anteriormente calculada e divida por 2). e imprima a mensagem "Aluno aprovado." (caso a média final seja 5.0 ou mais ) ou "Aluno reprovado.", (caso a média tenha ficado 4.9 ou menos)**. Para estes dois casos (aprovado ou reprovado após ter pego exame) apresente na última linha uma mensagem "Media final: " seguido da média final para esse aluno.

```
Entradas: 2.0, 4.0, 7.5, 8.0 

3.4 (Nota do Exame)
```

```
Saída:
Media: 5.4
Aluno em exame.
Nota do exame: 6.4
Aluno aprovado.
Media final: 5.9
```

Esse é o meu código até então:

```
let data = input.split(' ')
let exame = input.split('\n')


let N1 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let N2 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let N3 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let N4 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let notaExame = parseFloat(exame.shift())


let media = ((N1*2)+(N2*3)+(N3*4)+(N4*1))/10;
let mediaFinal = (parseFloat(exame) + parseFloat(media))/2

console.log("Media: " + media.toFixed(1))

if (media >= 7.0){
    console.log('Aluno aprovado.')
}else if (media.toFixed(1) >=5.0 && media.toFixed(1) <= 6.9){
    console.log('Aluno em exame.')
    console.log("Nota do exame: " + exame)
} else {
    console.log('Aluno Reprovado')
}
if (mediaFinal <= 4.9){
    console.log('Aluno reprovado.')
    console.log('Media final: ' + mediaFinal.toFixed(1))
} else {
    console.log('Aluno aprovado.')
    console.log('Media final: ' + mediaFinal.toFixed(1))
}
```

O meu principal problema, é que quando o resultado é superior a 5.0 ou 7.0, onde o aluno é automaticamente aprovado ou reprovado, a saída está sendo essa:

```
Media: 7.3
Aluno aprovado.
Aluno aprovado.
Media final: 5.3
```

O ideal é que a saída seja essa:

```
Media: 7.3
Aluno aprovado.
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi não são todos os alunos que fazem exame mas apenas os que ficaram com média >= 5 e < 7. Apenas estes alunos farão exame e terão o cálculo da média final.

Comment: É só trocar onde está `let input = prompt("Entre com as notas")` coloca `let input = require("fs").readFileSync("stdin", "utf8");`.

Comment: Tenho que reverter sua edição pois o [Stack Overflow não é um Forum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), veja em [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) que somos um site de perguntas e respostas. O nosso formato [não aceita mudança de foco na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6375/137387) uma vez que já tenha obtido respostas, pois assim invalida as respostas e os votos. Se tiver novo questionamento ou faça ao autor da resposta nos comentários ou [abra nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 4):

A primeira coisa que quero dizer é que as pessoas andam aprendendo pedir dados que precisam ser entrados de uma forma específica e isso é uma praga. Já é complicado digitar certo de forma mais livre, ter que escrever formatado é pior ainda. E as pessoas não validam se realmente digitaram algo válido. E aprendem errado que entrada de dados é sempre linda e perfeita.

Dito isto, a lógica está errada porque o enunciado não é seguido. Se o seguí-lo já dá uma ideia melhor do que deve fazer. A nota de exame nem deve ser pedida se o aluno não está em exame, porque essa nota não existe. Programar é entender o problema, é resolver um problema real e não algo ficcional que não existe na prática.

Como ler o dado só se for necessário? Coloca isso dentro do condicional que estabelece que precisa. Aí obviamente que a comparação é que determinará se o resultado final também estará condicionado. É só interpretar o enunciado como ele está escrito (quando ele está certo, o que parece ser o caso).

```js
let input = prompt("Entre com as notas")
let data = input.split(' ')
let N1 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let N2 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let N3 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let N4 = parseFloat(data.shift());
let media = (N1 * 2 + N2 * 3 + N3 * 4 + N4 * 1) / 10;
console.log("Media: " + media.toFixed(1))
if (media >= 7.0) {
    console.log('Aluno aprovado.')
}else if (media.toFixed(1) >=5.0 && media.toFixed(1) <= 6.9){
    console.log('Aluno em exame.')
    let notaExame = prompt("Entre com a nota do exame");
    let mediaFinal = (parseFloat(notaExame) + parseFloat(media))/2
    if (mediaFinal <= 4.9){
        console.log('Aluno reprovado.')
        console.log('Media final: ' + mediaFinal.toFixed(1))
    } else {
        console.log('Aluno aprovado.')
        console.log('Media final: ' + mediaFinal.toFixed(1))
    }
    console.log("Nota do exame: " + notaExame)
} else {
    console.log('Aluno Reprovado')
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FinalExam.js).

O `let` não funciona em qualquer navegador.

Pode organizar melhor, e pode validar todas entradas, mas assim resolve.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, eles foram muito úteis! 

Estou editando a minha dúvida, espero que possa me ajudar novamente.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo